# What are the approaches to get a list of online meetings or team calls?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to get a list of teams online meetings and teams calls using Microsoft Graph API, I found next methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http for getting meetings or calls by id, join url (for meetings) etc. But how can I get these ids/urls etc?

Comment: I think you can use [list calendar event api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  `/me/calendar/events?$filter=isOnlineMeeting eq 'true'`

Comment: I didn't test it because I don't have test resource, the only point I'm not sure is whether we can add filter on property `isOnlineMeeting`. If we can't, we may need to write a custom data filter in our code.